# views webform submission username

Tags: views, webforms

I would like to have webform submission username using views.
Add fields > webform submissions: user
The result is uid (user id number)

How can I have username login name instead of uid ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

'Username' as a field is not available to webform as it is not stored in the webform submission.

You need to add a Relationship to the User using the UID and then the User Name will be available to you in the fields section.

See more about relationships in [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mRWtpcUm9pI#t=294)